# Cannot use an Id retreived by getFieldValue into @wire getRecord

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire, getfieldvalue

I have an Account lookup field which gets Account ID, and need to get its Account Name on field change. (This is a Home tab component using Opportunity Form)

**HTML (lightning-record-edit-form; object-api-name = Opportunity)**

```
<lightning-input-field field-name={oppAccountField} onchange={handleAccountChange} required></lightning-input-field>
```

**JS**

```
accountId = '';

@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: '$accountId',
    fields: [ ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD ]
})
thisAccount({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
            console.log('got data');
            this.accountName = getFieldValue(data, ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD);
    }
    if (error) {
        console.log('error');
        handleError(error);
    }
}

    handleAccountChange(e) {
            this.accountId = getFieldValue(e.detail.value, ACCOUNT_ID_FIELD);
            console.log('new acc Id: ' + this.accountId); //shows correct id
    }
```

Tis updates the this.accountId with accurate id, but does not @wire getRecord. Also, the getRecord works perfectly if I just hardcode random Id inside handleAccountChange(), but not even error console log runs after assigning accountId through getFieldValue. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using this component on the org home page?

Comment: Yes. please note, the retreived ID is even printed by: console.log('new acc Id: ' + this.accountId); - see last line of code. Indicating that accountId (which is a dynamic param $accountId) has indeed been updated, which should trigger @wire, but it does not, no console logs run inside \@wire getRecord no error, nothing

Comment: Its because the record id is not available on the home page, it is available only on the detail page of the object.

Comment: Ok, then Why does the last line: console.log('new acc Id: ' + this.accountId); show the said record ID? I am getting it through lightning-input-field

Comment: @Dextersecret I update my answer, you need two wire methods if you need to access another object than one in your object-api-name.

Comment: @Dextersecret Ohh!! got you, you are using it in record form and you need an account id.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. For convenience I've dropped simplest version to recreate this error in a playground (obviously, not linked to org data):
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/jumhrb_4c/7/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to use `getFieldValue` to get id from `e.detail.value`.

Change this line

```
this.accountId = getFieldValue(e.detail.value, OPP_ACCOUNTID_FIELD);
```

To

```
this.accountId = e.detail.value[0];
```

More info according to the docs

> Use the event.detail.value property to retrieve the Id of the selected
>   contact record on the lookup field. Although the Id is returned in an
>   array, multi-select lookups are currently not supported. This example
>   also uses the success event to return the saved record. For more
>   information on the success event, see the lightning-record-edit-form
>   documentation.

[Refer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation)

**The reason why you didn't recognize that it's an array**

```
let ids = ['someidsdfsdfsdf'];
console.log('ids => ' + ids); // Output: ids => someidsdfsdfsdf
console.log('ids => ', ids);  // Output: ids =>  ["someidsdfsdfsdf"]
```

To avoid this you can either use `,` instead of `+` in the log as in the second console log.

**Note: It's a good idea to remove the unwanted logs after debugging.**

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks Rahul, I was going mad.And I was just about to ask you for a doc reference, but you already got it, and we have learned that the array will sometime work for multi-select fields. Strange how when I console.log e.detail.value, it does not show that it is an array.

Comment: @Dextersecret If there is only one element in the array and if you log in on the console, it shows that element without mentioning that its an array. I will update that as well in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
recordId = '';

@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: '$recordId',
    fields: []
})
thisOpportunity({ error, data }) {
}
```

and the wire for account

```
accountId = '';

@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: '$accountId',
    fields: [ ACCOUNT_NAME_FIELD ]
})
thisAccount({ error, data }) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a Name, not Id. Neither one of these are provided by getRecord, it just does not run, no Console.logs are run inside @wire data result

Comment: you said "and need to get its Account Name on field change. (Homepage context component)" the "Homepage" is the Homepage of which object?

Comment: It's a global context - living on a home tab

Comment: The recordId is required, if it's not provided the wire method doesn't run.

Comment: It is there, it's even printed by: console.log('new acc Id: ' + this.accountId);
Indicating that accountId (which is a dynamic param $accountId) has indeed been updated, which should trigger @wire, but it does not. no error, nothing.